Can partial derivatives help solve systems of elementary equations?
Let's say I have two systems of two equations,
$x\ y = P(x,y)$ and $y+x = Q(x,y)$, where $P$ and $Q$ are rational functions.
If $P$ and $Q$ are simple enough, this might be solvable via traditional substitution methods.
But, is there a way that partial derivatives could speed up or generalize the process to successfully aid in solving for x and y? I've never heard of partial derivatives actually allowing one to solve an algebra problem, but it seems like a neat idea if it's possible.
I'm inclined to think the answer is no. If you could solve polynomial equations by taking derivatives, then you could violate the abel ruffini theorem by taking derivatives of a quintic polynomial and solving it via knowledge of a quartic's roots.
But, on the other hand, if you have the good fortune of being able to use x-y re-arrangements and substitutions to decompose your complicated polynomial into two solvable rational expressions, maybe that's a different story.
